# Crystal Reports exception when calling ExportToDisk

Tags: exception, crystal-reports

I'm getting some weird behavior with Crystal Reports (version distributed with Visual Studio 2008).  I can view the report normally, but attempts to use `ExportToDisk` fail with the following exception:

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.InvalidArgumentException:
>
> This group section cannot be printed
>   because its condition field is
>   nonexistent or invalid.  Format the
>   section to choose another condition
>   field. Error in File
>   C:\DOCUME~1\gbuehler\LOCALS~1\Temp\Report
>   {2FD9516D-0FD4-4D20-A326-D21EB762EB9E}.rpt:
>   Invalid group condition. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x8000020B):
>
> This group section cannot be printed
>   because its condition field is
>   nonexistent or invalid.  Format the
>   section to choose another condition
>   field. Error in File
>   C:\DOCUME~1\developer\LOCALS~1\Temp\Report
>   {2FD9516D-0FD4-4D20-A326-D21EB762EB9E}.rpt:
>   Invalid group condition.    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions
>   pExportOptions, RequestContext
>   pRequestContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext
>   reqContext)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType
>   formatType, String fileName)    at
>   LSPayroll.MainForm.btnSendCanadian_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents
>   and Settings\developer\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\MainForm.cs:line
>   277

A cursory search for `Invalid Group Condition` returns other users looking for solutions and recommendations to recreate the report. Can someone give a logical reason why the report can be viewed normally, but `ExportToDisk` fails with an exception?

Not sure if it helps, but this is the code I'm using to create the report document and export:

```
// build a crystal reports document in memory and use the crystal 
// reports library to export as a PDF
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
reportDocument.SetDataSource(data);
reportDocument.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "payroll.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled to find a solution to this problem

The solution that worked for me

In the statement

```
reportDocument.SetDataSource(data);
```

ensure that 'data' is a reference to a DataSet and not a DataTable.

Comment: Your answer needs a little more context

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a DataTable, and it works fine:

```
public ActionResult ReporteUsuarios() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try {
            SqlConnection con = (SqlConnection)seguridad.Database.Connection;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select nombre from usuarios", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new HttpException(500, "Hubo un problema con la base de datos. " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
        }

        ReportClass rpt = new ReportClass();
        rpt.FileName = Server.MapPath("/Reports/Usuarios.rpt");
        rpt.Load();
        rpt.SetDataSource(dt);

        Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "Usuarios.pdf");
    }
```